# Can not add delete button to all rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
function GetEmp() {
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "EMService.asmx/GetEmployee",
     data: '{}',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg, status, metaData) {
            if (msg.d && msg.d.length > 0) {
                BindTable(msg.d); 
            }
        },
 });
}
```

to bind the json(collection)

```
function BindTable(data) {
    $('#tblEmployee tr:gt(0)').remove();
    $("#employeeTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#tblEmployee");
}

<script id="employeeTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td>${Id}</td> 
        <td>${Code}</td>
        <td>${Name}</td>
     </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the a delete button in your template, and bind an event handler ([event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) works great here):

```
<script id="employeeTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td>${Id}</td> 
        <td>${Code}</td>
        <td>${Name}</td>
        <td><button data-id="${Id}" class=".delete" type="button">Delete</button></td>
     </tr>
</script>
```

And the event handler:

```
$('#tblEmployee').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.data('id');
    // this is where you would make the Ajax call to remove the record from
    // the server
    deleteRecord(id).then(function() {
       // at some point, e.g. after the Ajax request was successful, you  
       // would also remove the row
       $this.closest('tr).remove();
    });
});
```

Where `deleteRecord` would look something like:

```
function deleteRecord(id) {
    return $.ajax({ ... });
}
```

This makes use of the jqXHR's promise interface. You can find more [about promises in the jQuery tutoria](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/)l.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, you can add Delete button to every row with different ids

```
function BindTable(data) {
    $('#tblEmployee tr:gt(0)').remove();
    $("#employeeTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#tblEmployee");
}
```

Add the button to the template

```
<tr>
    <td>${Id}</td> 
    <td>${Code}</td>
    <td>${Name}</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Delete" id="delete${Id}"></td>
</tr>
```